# Referencing an imported font URL from a script

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

I am trying to use the `pdfmake` package in an app; in order to load fonts, a list of URLs is provided at initialization. But my fonts are managed by npm and Vite, so do not have fixed URLs. Here's where I've gotten so far:

```bash
npm install @fontsource/source-sans-pro
```

In `app.js`:

```js
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import "@fontsource/source-sans-pro/latin-400.css"
import "@fontsource/source-sans-pro/latin-400-italic.css"
import "@fontsource/source-sans-pro/latin-700.css"
import "@fontsource/source-sans-pro/latin-700-italic.css"

pdfMake.fonts = {
    SourceSans: {
        normal: "", // need to provide URLs for the WOFF files
        bold: "",
        italics: "",
        bolditalics: ""
    },
};
```

When I run `npm run build` I get this in the output:

```
✓ 636 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json                                               6.12 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-400-italic-500f8aaf.woff2     14.16 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-700-italic-fae9ee8d.woff2     14.20 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-700-normal-0d0a6262.woff2     14.71 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-400-normal-7b348b30.woff2     14.89 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-700-italic-1933b21f.woff      17.68 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-400-italic-c3707996.woff      17.76 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-700-normal-bcc2a2ed.woff      18.39 kB
public/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-400-normal-69491b82.woff      18.42 kB
```

So the fonts are easily accessible at, e.g. `https://example.com/build/assets/source-sans-pro-latin-400-normal-69491b82.woff` but of course this is a dynamic URL.

How can I get that URL for use by my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `import.meta.url` to get the URL for your assets. Vite will perform necessary transforms so that the URLs still point to the correct location even after bundling and asset hashing:

```js
const fontUrl = new URL("FONT_PATH", import.meta.url).href;
```

Here's the supporting [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url).

Comment: Where is `new URL` coming from? Or `import.meta.url`? And what about the font path – buried somewhere in `node_modules/` – should I just hope it doesn't change?

Comment: `URL` is a API built into JavaScript that represents any URL. `import.meta.url` is also built into JavaScript, and contains information about the environment. As for the font path, it should stay the same unless FontSource changes their system, just like with the CSS files.

Comment: In FontSource, I believe the font files are stored under `@fontsource/source-sans-pro/files`.

Comment: It’s a bit ugly but it works!

Comment: Yeah. Honestly I'd recommend just downloading the font files themselves, since FontSource is generally for use in an application, but this works too.